# android mediaplayer get playing url

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm interested in retrieving the current url or uri  of a Media Player.
if i run :

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

is there a way i get the url this media player is running?

Comment: You meant to say file name of media?

Comment: Yes , i need to know what is the url that was passed to this media player .I need to know what url or uri is the mediaplayer playing. A string containing what is playing example "http://localhost/a.m3u8" or what is it palyaing , in that moment.Let's say my initial "String url" become null and i want to get it back , just for example.

Comment: Yes there is a way to get that url. Wait for my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class CustomMediaPlayer extends MediaPlayer
{
    String dataSource;

    @Override
    public void setDataSource(String path) throws IOException, IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setDataSource(path);
        dataSource = path;
    }

    public String getDataSource()
    {
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Use this CustomMediaPlayer class instead to MediaPlayer to get the current url that is passed to the MediaPlayer.

I hope this code might help you in getting the url using:

```
String url = "http://........"; // your URL here
CustomMediaPlayer customMediaPlayer = new CustomMediaPlayer ();
customMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
customMediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
customMediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
customMediaPlayer.start();
String url1 = customMediaPlayer.getDataSource();// get your url here
```

Comment: Very good answer, thank you very much .Good idea. But do you think this can be done using reflection in place of extending the media player class?

Comment: My app is using a webview that display video , using MediaPlayer ,and i wish to know what is the url the MediaPlayer is playing , so I can not directly extend the media player class , but I think reflection can do it.But i do not know exactly how to do it

Comment: i need to research on that. if i get something will let you now